# Got all the fields 2 times on web page

Tags: python, html, django

My models.py file contain different field name then forms.py file
Radiobuttonlist displays as dropdownlist as well as radiobuttonlist on web page

I want placeholder instead of names again all the fields

And what is the reason behind that 2 times printed fields???

Comment: Could you give a sample of your code?

Comment: Okay...I will give